# jar/zip files caching in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, caching, jar, eclipse-plugin

I want know how jar/zip files are read by eclipse. I mean is a jar file read everytime when needed or it is cached. I found that there is a ZipCache which stores the open jar files.

can anyone plss tell me how these files are read and what is the algorithm?

Thanks !!
Swapnil

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager$ZipCache`?

That holds open ZipFiles as JDT searches for classes and source in its model.  Anyone that needs to access the contents of the jar goes through the cache to get the ZipFile.

There is code in the JavaModelManager that occasionally flushes the cache, probably in response to events like a project close.

Comment: HI Paul....

Thanks for your reply Ya i meant org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager$ZipCache

are all the Jar files that are opened for reading read through this cache?

Also if Jar files are not written what is the need for flushing it back?

I am new to all this...could you plss answer

How big is the cache size?
How frequently is the cache flushed back
And what is the eviction policy of the cache
Thanks and awaiting your reply

Comment: This applies to JDT managing its access to jar files, to load classes and resources, and to allow JDT to build its ASTs so it can analyze project source files.  Why do you care about an internal implementation detail?